# Problem with returning a class type object having a pointer member

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-errors, runtime-error

Ok, so I'm new to OOP and currently working on learning dynamic objects. So recently I got an exercise to create a program to that takes two arrays and merge them into a new array and then sort the merged array, and I had to do this using classes. I almost completed the exercise but I'm stuck on one small point where I'm returning the object and copying it to new object but for some reason its giving me runtime error. All appropriate constructors including copy constructor and destructors are created.
Heres the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
class Array {
   int* num; // will point to the array of numbers
   int length; // will store the length of array
 public:
  //constructer & destructor
 Array() :num(NULL), length(0) {}; //default constructor
 Array(int len) { //parametrized constructor
    this->length = len;
    this->num = new int[this->length];
}
Array(const Array& obj) : length(obj.length) { //copy constructor/ deep copy
    this->num = new int[this->length];
    for (int c = 0; c < this->length; c++) {
        this->num[c] = obj.num[c];
    }
}

~Array() { // destructor
    delete[] this->num;
}

//methods
Array setLengthArr(int l) { // set length of the array manually
    this->length = l;
    this->num = new int[this->length];
    return *this;
}

Array inputArr() { //take input from user
    string temp; // to store input in string form
    cin.ignore(); // to ignore the /n when used cin before in main
    cout << "Enter Numbers Seperated By Space :" << endl; 
     getline(cin, temp); // take input in string
    istringstream is(temp); //pass the string to istringstream object 'is'
    int c = 0;
    while (c < length && is >> this->num[c]) { c++; } // divide the string based on space and put it in arr
    return *this;
}
Array merge_Array(Array &arr2) { // will take two arrays as input and merge them into new object
    Array merge_a(this->length + arr2.length);
    
    for (int c = 0; c < this->length; c++) { //add elements of first array to new array
        merge_a.num[c] = this->num[c];
    }
    
    for (int c = 0; c < arr2.length; c++) {  // add elements of 2nd array to the new array
        merge_a.num[merge_a.length - (c + 1)] = arr2.num[arr2.length - (c + 1)];
    }
    
    return merge_a;
}
Array SortArr() { // sort the given array in ascending order
    //Doing Selection Sort
    int min_ind=0, temp=0;
    for (int c = 0; c < this->length-1; c++) {
        min_ind = c;
        for (int i = c + 1; i < this->length; i++) {
            if (this->num[i] < this->num[min_ind]) {
                min_ind = i;
            }
        }
        temp = this->num[c];
        this->num[c] = this->num[min_ind];
        this->num[min_ind] = temp;
    }
    return *this;
}
void display() const {
    for (int c = 0; c < this->length; c++) {
        cout << this->num[c] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
};


 int main() {
 int len1, len2;
 cout << "Enter Length of Array 1 : "; cin >> len1;
 Array arr1(len1);
 arr1.inputArr();
 cout << endl;
 cout << "Enter Length of Array 2 : "; cin >> len2;
Array arr2(len2);
arr2.inputArr();
cout << endl;
Array merged_arr;
merged_arr = arr1.merge_Array(arr2);
cout << "Merged Array :" << endl;
merged_arr.display();

merged_arr.SortArr();
cout << "\nSorted Array :" << endl;
merged_arr.display();
}
```

So, I'm having the problem at this point:

```
Array merged_arr;
merged_arr = arr1.merge_Array(arr2);
```

I know there a better way to do this where I call the merge function using merged_arr and send arr1 and arr2 as arguement but I really want to know why this runtime error is happening, for future references.
Can anyone help me with this please..Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You should also define `operator=` which will implement a copy-assignment operator (in addition to your copy constructor). See the [Rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). Without this the compiler-generated copy assignment is copying the same pointer between both objects and therefore you'll run into a double deletion when the destructors of both `arr2` and `merged_arr` execute.

Comment: For an easy way to write the assignment operator, read up on the [Copy and Swap Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom). This trick is overkill for a small class like this, but copy and swap pretty much can't fail, making it an invaluable tool for later.

Comment: I think this is a genuine duplicate of [What is the Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three#:~:text=Rule%20of%20three%20in%20C%2B%2B,other%20two%20members%20functions%20together)  It is the cause of this runtime error.

Comment: *All appropriate constructors including copy constructor and destructors are created.* -- The book you're using, or the teacher that gave you this assignment, didn't mention the *assignment operator*?  If not, then the book is lacking, or the teacher is lacking, or the teacher did this on purpose for you to do your own research.  This: `merged_arr = arr1.merge_Array(arr2);` bypasses all of the code you wrote and calls the default assignment operator, which does what you don't want it to do.

Comment: Thanks guys. read up that rule of three and did solve the problem.

Comment: Extra handy rules for later: [Five and Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Indeed - modern C++ doesn't use much explicit `new` and `delete`.  Therefore no need for an explicit destructor.  Therefore Rule of 0 is common.  And nice.